# responsive filemanager with tinymce in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, tinymce, responsive-filemanager

i am using responsive filemanager with tinymce in codeigniter

the problem is when i select an image to insert in editor, image is not showing due to wrong image path

my page url is: http://website.com/media/index.php/post/add_new?post_type=news

when i select an image it makes an image path like this:

```
<img src="/media/index.php/post//source/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" alt="" />
```

if i remove "index.php/post/" it works fine, how i can remove it

my responsive filemanager configuration

```
$base_url = "http://website.com";
$upload_dir = '/source/';
$current_path = '../source/';
$thumbs_base_path = '../thumbs/';
```

tinymce configuration

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea.editor",theme: "modern",width: 830,height: 300,
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste responsivefilemanager"
    ],
    toolbar1: "undo redo | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | styleselect",
   toolbar2: "| responsivefilemanager | link unlink anchor | image media | forecolor backcolor  | print preview code ",
   relative_urls:false,
   image_advtab: true ,
   external_filemanager_path:"/media/filemanager/",
   filemanager_title:"Responsive Filemanager" ,
   external_plugins: { "filemanager" : "/media/filemanager/plugin.min.js"}
 });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you badly config connector.php file that connect tiny to file manager, you should set url correctly!